# How to interpret cv.glmnet() plot?

Tags: r, cross-validation, interpretation, lasso

I performed lasso and then leave-one-out cross validation

```
cv<-cv.glmnet(df, df$Price, nfolds = 1500)
```

When I plot cv I get the following:
[image]

I also noticed that I get 2 different lambdas: `lambda.min` and `lambda.1se`

- What is the difference between these lambdas?
- What can I understand from the above plot in general (what are these confidence intervals about, what are the two dotted lines etc)?

If I change to `nfolds=10` to perform 10-fold validation, I get different `lambda.1se` and different coefficients for this lambda. Based on what criterio can I choose the best for me?

Comment: Have you tried looking here: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html

Comment: @ilanman That is great, thank you ! But still which lambda should I prefer? My intuition would say lambda.min but I see that lambda.1se is usually suggested..

Comment: what does the number above mean? Is this also the number of non-zero coefficients as the plot of glmnet?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This isn't really about statistics, just reading the documentation.

- The two different values of $\lambda$ reflect two common choices for $\lambda$. The $\lambda_{\min}$ is the one which minimizes out-of-sample loss in CV. The $\lambda_{1se}$ is the one which is the largest $\lambda$ value within 1 standard error of $\lambda_{\min}$. One line of reasoning suggests using $\lambda_{1se}$ because it hedges against overfitting by selecting a larger $\lambda$ value than the min. Which choice is best is context-dependent.
- The intervals estimate variance of the loss metric (red dots). They're computed using CV.
- The vertical lines show the locations of $\lambda_{\min}$ and $\lambda_{1se}$.
- The numbers across the top are the number of nonzero coefficient estimates.